# How to use HStack to fill equally to the very edge of the View?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch-complication

How can I make the HStack fill equally to the very edge of the View like yellow arrows indicate in the screenshot?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
var labelList = ["0", "6", "12", "6", "0"]
HStack {
    ForEach(labelList, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .font(.system(size: 8))
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Spacer after Text

```
var labelList = ["0", "6", "12", "6", "0"]
HStack {
    ForEach(labelList, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .font(.system(size: 8))
        if labelList.last != item {
            Spacer()
        }
    }
```